# Bootstrap popover with angular 2 App

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

In the angular 2 app, I'm displaying a popover when a button clicked using jQuery. But typescript throwing an error

```
 Object doesn't support property or method 'popover'
```

My component

```
/// <reference path="../shared/bootstrap.ts" />


 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import * as $ from 'jquery';


  @Component({
    selector: 'my-calender',
    templateUrl: `
       <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="openPopover()">Disply Popup</a>
     `
  })

export class CalenderComponent implements OnInit {  

    openPopover(): void {

       var that: any = this;

        $(that).popover({
        title: 'My Popover'

       });
     }
```

Typescript compilation is fine. But when I run the app and click that button to shows the popup, it throwing the above error.

But Other boostrap default functionalities are working as expected (nav bar, dropdown).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` is not that..

`this` refers to the `CalendarComponent` class. I suggest looking a little more at the tutorials. TypeScript/ES6 has the neat feature that you don't really have to worry about the `this` context any more. As long as you use `() => {}` arrow function notations.

In the meantime you can try something like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-calender',
    templateUrl: `
       <a class="btn btn-success btn-sm" (click)="openPopover($event.currentTarget)">Disply Popup</a>
     `
})    
export class CalenderComponent implements OnInit {  

    openPopover(target: HTMLElement): void {
       $(target).popover({
        title: 'My Popover'
       });
    }
}
```

You can access the event property within a template using the `$event` variable. This will contain a `MouseEvent` on click. `MouseEvent` has a currentTarget property which contains the HtmlElement on which the event was placed. From there you can intialise your `jQuery` function.

Another idea could be to use [`@ViewChild`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/ViewChild-decorator.html), but you will find plenty of examples if you check out the guides and cookbooks at [angular.io](https://angular.io).

**edit**

If after all this it still doesn't work, you should make sure you added the tooltip plugin (`tooltip.js`) to your project. Bootstrap needs this to enable `popover`

Comment: I have changed to pass the htmlElement and tried that. but it still showing the same error. I tried to debug the code with chrome dev tools no luck.
may be way bootstrap loaded is wrong?

Comment: @Aroor I guess you didn't change the template? I changed the event method call: `(click)="openPopover($event.currentTarget)"`

Comment: yes i did change that. My question is, can we use the current bootstrap library with angular 2 app? or we have to use a wrapper like ng-bootstrap or ng2-bootstrap? are you able to produce a working sample with bootstrap library?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an extra thing you probably forgot. To answer your other question, my preference would be to use `ng-bootstrap` though. But you can do whatever you like best

Answer (score 1):

In Angular context it is better to use a dedicated, native libraries that provide much better API for the Angular users. There is an excellent implementation for Angular and Bootstrap 4: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io. By using it you could skip the whole jQuery / Bootstrap JS story.

Using Bootstrap's JS means that you would have to load jQuery, Bootstrap's JS and potentially create Angular wrappers around Bootstrap's JS code. But even doing so would result in rather poor integration since both jQuery and Angular would "fight" over DOM updates - the philosophy of those 2 libraries is *very* different.

On the other hand using popovers from [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) is very easy:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" placement="top"
        ngbPopover="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." popoverTitle="Popover on top">
  Popover on top
</button>
```

In the above example `ngbPopover` directive is all that is needed! You can see in action in a working plunk http://plnkr.co/edit/MiUo2BOPJCVkiVxRT6or?p=preview and check more examples / documentation on https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover

Comment: yes i tried that as well, but in this case i am dynamically adding the popover to that element. because i am working on a calendar, i wanted to dynamically add the content to that popover. is that some things those libraries supported? in the sample code i produced here just a testing purpose

Comment: You can use property binding for that `[ngbPopover]="variable"`. check this [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/ysBYdAObmzuZOTvyxHIP?p=preview)